# rolling function to get coeff of regression from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, rollapply

I want to get coefficient of regression for each data frame in a list of dataframes with a rolling period but somehow I am getting very different result from what I am looking for.
I have tried the following code:
my data looks like this

```
library("zoo") ## for rollapply()
data <- list(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars)

fapplyFunction <- function(x){
coef(lm(mpg ~ drat, data=as.data.frame(x)))}

coef_list <- lapply(data, rollapply, 20, fapplyFunction, partial = FALSE, by.column = FALSE)
```

I wish to get regression result for each element for rolling windows as a list ,which I can later bind

I am new to `R`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes that is from zoo package .@jogo

Comment: The last line refers to `fapplyFunction` but you have defined `fapplyFunction2`.  Make sure the function names are the same.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it here. Thanks @G.Grothendieck

Comment: The code now gives the result you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a `data.frame` as the first `rollapply` argument will apply `FUN` to every column of the `data.frame` *separately*. Operating on data from *two columns simultaneously* can be achieved by moving a rolling window across the the sequence of row numbers in the `data.frame`.

```
lapply(data, function(x)
    rollapply(1:nrow(x), 20, function(i) coef(lm(mpg ~ drat, data = x[i, ]))))
#[[1]]
#      (Intercept)     drat
# [1,]   -11.70889 8.981350
# [2,]   -12.09923 9.124252
# [3,]   -11.47530 9.015324
# [4,]   -11.91551 9.124458
# [5,]   -12.51405 9.094820
# [6,]   -12.10843 8.994363
# [7,]   -15.57941 9.937651
# [8,]   -14.06719 9.511583
# [9,]   -14.42693 9.684131
#[10,]   -11.68393 8.789089
#[11,]   -12.12158 8.954089
#[12,]   -13.12850 9.243443
#[13,]   -12.81957 9.095040
# 
#[[2]]
#      (Intercept)     drat
# [1,]   -11.70889 8.981350
# [2,]   -12.09923 9.124252
# [3,]   -11.47530 9.015324
# [4,]   -11.91551 9.124458
# [5,]   -12.51405 9.094820
# [6,]   -12.10843 8.994363
# [7,]   -15.57941 9.937651
# [8,]   -14.06719 9.511583
# [9,]   -14.42693 9.684131
#[10,]   -11.68393 8.789089
#[11,]   -12.12158 8.954089
#[12,]   -13.12850 9.243443
#[13,]   -12.81957 9.095040
# 
#[[3]]
#      (Intercept)     drat
# [1,]   -11.70889 8.981350
# [2,]   -12.09923 9.124252
# [3,]   -11.47530 9.015324
# [4,]   -11.91551 9.124458
# [5,]   -12.51405 9.094820
# [6,]   -12.10843 8.994363
# [7,]   -15.57941 9.937651
# [8,]   -14.06719 9.511583
# [9,]   -14.42693 9.684131
#[10,]   -11.68393 8.789089
#[11,]   -12.12158 8.954089
#[12,]   -13.12850 9.243443
#[13,]   -12.81957 9.095040
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, you're right, I was mistaken; I made an edit to clarify. It doesn't change the solution nor approach though.

Comment: rollapply only applies to each column separately if by.column = TRUE but the code in the question uses by.column = FALSE.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck By default (and in my example) we have `by.column = TRUE`. The goal in the original question was to extract coefficients based on a linear model that considers rolling data from two columns. My solution does exactly that. Perhaps you want to post a different solution to illustrate an alternative approach.

Comment: @philomath Please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you will help future SO readers identify relevant Q&As and keep SO tidy.

Comment: @MauritsEvers done.  I am new to stack overflow.Thanks.